# Convert XmlElement to XElement with Elements("ElementName") Returns No Results

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I'm using the following code to convert a `XmlElement` to `XElement`

```
public staic XElement ToXElement(this XmlNode node) {
    XElement element = null;
    if (null != node) {
        element = XElement.Parse(node.OuterXml);
    }
    return element;
}
```

However when I call `Elements()` or `Elements("ElementName")` I get no results.
I do however get results from calling `Nodes()`.

Why don't the elements come up from calling Elements and what's the difference between the two methods?

Here is a snippit of the xml I'm parsing.

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ElementManifests>
        <ElementFile Location="Path/file.xml"/>
    </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in your "ElementName"?

Comment: Provided the "ElementName" is correct, does your element has a namespace ? If so, I think it should appear when you call Elements(

Comment: Add a sample if the XML node (as text).

Comment: Give us an example of the xml that node.OuterXml contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably not using the namespace correctly. Both of these methods work correctly for me:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("test.xml"); //or result of ToXElement
foreach(var item in root.Elements())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}

XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/";
var manifestsNode = root.Element(ns + "ElementManifests");
```

Given that you don't know the difference between the `Elements()` (get all direct children) and `Element()` (get one specific direct child element) you should start with a Linq to Xml tutorial.

Comment: I'm familiar with System.Xml.Linq, and I'm not using `Load` i'm using `Parse`, I think that might make the difference. Also the namespace is not the issue as `Elements()` should still return a result.

Comment: Yes - `Elements()` should produce results (and does for me using your sample xml). There isn't really any difference between the results of `Load` and `Parse` - one is for loading XML from a file, one for parsing an XML string. Can you verify that you are passing the full XML to the `ToXElement` method?

Comment: That must mean my problem actually lies elsewhere, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Test this code:

```
var Status = xn["Feature"];
foreach (XmlElement element in Status) {
    XElement withoutXmlnsElement =RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement.Parse(element.OuterXml));
}

public static XElement RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement e) {
    return new XElement(e.Name.LocalName,
    (from n in e.Nodes()
    select ((n is XElement) ? RemoveAllNamespaces(n as XElement) : n)),
    (e.HasAttributes) ? (from a in e.Attributes() 
    where (!a.IsNamespaceDeclaration) select new     
    XAttribute(a.Name.LocalName,a.Value)) : null);
}
```